# Submitting form and getting response without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, django

I was making this simple BMR calculator app the problem is when I submit I don't want to go to any other page I want to show the results in the same page instead of having to go to another page.

In my `views.py`

```
def bmrvalue(age, height, weight, gender):
    if gender == 'm':
        BMR = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5
    else:
        BMR = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) - 161
    return BMR 


def MyBmr(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BmrForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            age    = form.cleaned_data['age']
            height = form.cleaned_data['height']
            weight = form.cleaned_data['weight']
            gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
            mybmr  = bmrvalue(age,height,weight,gender)

            return render (request, 'resultes.html', {'bmr':mybmr })
    else:
        form = BmrForm()

    return render (request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front end code required for this (place in your HTML) notice that I said required pretty much other than web sockets this is the way to do this:

```
<script>
function calculateResultsAndPost(){
const gender = document.getElementById('gender')
const weight = document.getElementById('weight')
const height = document.getElementById('height')
const age = document.getElementById('age')
const BMR = (10 * weight ) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age ) + gender.isChecked ? 5 : - 161
// if you really need this on the server
fetch('/my-python-api-endpoint/bmr', {
method: 'POST',
body: {body:
     {
       BMR: BMR,
       otherData: otherData,
       weight: weight,
       gender: gender.isChecked,
       age: age
     }
})

}
</script>
```

The logic in this for needs to move to JavaScript including all the math there seems to be no reason for serverside interaction here at all, but in case you need it those requests need to happen not using the

The only way to get data to the backend without making the page fully refresh is through JavaScript (whether new WebSocket(), XMLHttpRequest()/fetch()). If you submit a form with an action and method it will refresh the page there are no if ands or buts about this (well you can be really hacky and place that in an iFrame and have the iFrame refresh).

The backend Django code required:

In `urls.py`
    from django.urls import path

```
from . import views

app_name = 'bmr'
urlpatterns = [
    path('/bmr', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

In `views.py`. All this is a vague approximation

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import User


class IndexView(generic.ListView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Accepts XMLHttpRequests"""
        user = User.create(processRequest(request.body))
        return JsonResponse(user.toJSON())
    # or more simply:
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = User.create(processRequest(request.body))
    return JsonResponse(user.toJSON())
```

From the Django docs:

> HttpRequest.body¶ The raw HTTP request body as a byte string. This is
>   useful for processing data in different ways than conventional HTML
>   forms: binary images, XML payload etc. For processing conventional
>   form data, use HttpRequest.POST.
>
> You can also read from an HttpRequest using a file-like interface. See
>   HttpRequest.read().

Comment: i understand that i can move the logic to the frontend by  taking the value of inputs do the math  and display that in another element . but i'm  doing it in the back end because i'm going to save the data for authenticated user and do something with it . but for the moment i wanna know if i can capture this data that i'm currently working with and display it  instead of redirecting to results page

Comment: yes so like I said you must use the fetch() method or if you're feeling old school new XMLHTTPRequest() which will allow you to make API requests to your python server at an endpoint that accepts "application/json". One of the easier ways to accomplish this is use Django rest framework or if you want to not then you can simply have a get(req, res){